# How to read folders in subfolder using PHP

Tags: php, directory

Hi guys I know this is quite simple but i spend to much time in this kind of problem

I have folders ...

Main Folder

- img_gallery (sub folder)
- Front-end (sub folder)

  - sample.php
- sample2.php

all the uploaded image will be save in img_gallery (sub folder)
but when i display the image in sample.php under Front-end (sub-folder) it doesnt work ... but when I create sample2.php (with same code) the image is shown

I am using this kind of code ,. but its not working..

```
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
  $path .= "/img_gallery";
  include_once($path);
```

Thank you in advance for those who will help me :)

Comment: Can you show the code from sample.php that should display the image

Comment: you just want to read sub folde or you want to read all image file inside folder

Comment: Your question needs to be rewritten. You first speak about dispalying images, and your code is including folders like php scripts.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :) but its not working ... here's the code for displaying the image  <img src="<?php echo $row['project_img1']?>" alt="..." width="600">

Comment: @saty the $row['project_img1'] stores the path of the image ... i dont know why it doesnt read the image when i use in subfolder

Comment: chmod give permission to directory 0755

Answer (score 0):

Use ../ insteed of only '/'

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "../img_gallery";
include_once($path);
```

Comment: use this                                                                                                                <img src="../img_gallery/<?php echo $row['project_img1']?>" alt="..." width="600">

Answer (score 0):

Try another path $path_new = "../img_gallery" in the includes of sample.php

Answer (score 0):

Acually, you're doing include on a folder. Don't think you can do this acually.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
$path .= "/img_gallery";
include_once($path);
```

So:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
$path .= "/img_gallery/sample.php";
include_once($path);
```

Or:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
$path .= "/sample2.php";
include_once($path);
```

Remember, that include includes php script files, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all of your answers 
sorry if you might confused :)

I answered it correctly

I just need to change the path directory whenever i save the data in database

answer is

../img_gallery

just need to add ../

thank you ^_^

cheers for the great programmers

Answer (score -1):

We usually define a constant to represent the root directory, like

`define ('BASEPATH', __DIR__);`

instead of using

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Why not simply use ``__DIR__`` instead of defining BASEPATH ? Two constants with same value?

Comment: BASEPATH is defined only once in an index file, other files include it, then, we can use it like:
`include BASEPATH . '/path/to/file';`
This is quite clear

Comment: But why define it in first place. When you can use ``__DIR__`` instead?